# VS Code snippet code option problem on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my VS code editor i cannot read snippet code option.
let's see the image:
[Code option is not readable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4yRh.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue I solved it by uninstalling the extension from Microsoft. I guess the update went wrong and didn't add the snippets to whatever VS Code uses to look for snippets. After uninstalling the extension and reinstalling, I can confirm it works again.

Do check if your other code snippet are working by clicking `CTRL + SPACE`